# pause/play multiple embedded youtube players

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube

I have 2 thumbnail links, and when they are clicked on they open up videos in a lightbox style. My goal is to get them to play when they open and pause when they are closed (they close when the background area is clicked on).

My HTML code is here:

```
<body>
<div id="page">
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<a id="1" class="thumbnail"rel="nofollow"><img class="img1" src="Resources/thumb1.jpg"/></a>
<a id="2"class="thumbnail"rel="nofollow"><img class="img1"src="Resources/thumb2.jpg" /></a>

<div class="backdrop"></div>

<div class="Video"id="vid1" >
    <iframe  allowscriptaccess="always" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7xHXpebWtus?enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" id="iframe1"> </iframe>
</div>

<div class="Video"id="vid2">
    <iframe  allowscriptaccess="always" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PnAsZ1Roxj4?enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" id="iframe2"> </iframe>
</div>

<br /><br /><br /><br />
<h1>More To Come</h1>

</div>
```

And my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.thumbnail').click(function(){
    var $id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.backdrop, #vid'+ $id).animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
    $('#vid'+ $id).animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
    $('.backdrop, #vid'+ $id).css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.backdrop').click(function(){
                close_box();
});     

});


 function close_box()
{
    $('.backdrop,.Video').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
        $('.backdrop,.Video').css('display', 'none');
    });
};
```

I should probably mention that I am quite new to these languages!

Comment: Just as a side note... you will not be able to get it playing automatically on an iDevice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *YouTube Player API for iframe Embeds*. Here is the [reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to it.
 Instead of placing `iFRAME` tag, you create empty `DIV` with `ID` and `SCRIPT` tag with some *JavaScript* code. The code then generates an `iFRAME` and places it on the *DOM*, removing early created `DIV` and `SCRIPT` tags. This allows you to manipulate the `player` in the `SCRIPT` tag.
 Here is the working example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Mqbk/1/).

P.S. Also please pay attention to the "Requirements" section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use YouTube API.
[Here is tutorial](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)